# Why is String.format() not working on Android TextView?

Tags: java, android, textview

I am trying to format the text on an Android TextView. This is the code I tried in a Java console:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%-7s 56", "S"));
System.out.println(String.format("%-7s 56", "A(102)"));
```

The output is the expected, my text is left aligned:

```
S       56
A(102)  56
```

No I try the same code on Android TextView:

```
mTextView.setText(String.format("%-7s 56\n", "S"));
mTextView.append(String.format("%-7s 56", "A(102)"));
```

And this is the result:

[image]

As you can see the output is not the expected the text is not aligned. What I am doing wrong? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Did you try with a monospace font?

Comment: It works fine - the TextView has nothing to do with the generation o the string (`format`). The issue is that each letter has a "different rendered width" here. Typing in 10 `i`s and, on the next line, 10 `W`s should illustrate this.

Comment: Worked perfectly with Monospace font! Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was I was not using a Monospaced Font.

> A monospaced font, also called a fixed-pitch, fixed-width or
>   non-proportional font, is a font whose letters and characters each
>   occupy the same amount of horizontal space

So I only added this line before writing to the TextView:

```
mTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// I Think You Have To Achieve this in this way

// XML
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtCalValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

// Activity
    TextView txtCal;
    TextView txtCalValue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtCal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCal);
        txtCalValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCalValue);

        txtCal.setText("S\nA(102)");
        txtCalValue.setText("56\n56");

    }
```